# MVC and Export to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

**Description:**

I tried the following code in MVC and received "OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.". I followed the solution given in the URL http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC-custom-ActionResult.aspx. But my issue is not resolved.

Please help me to resolve this issue..

**Code:**

```
string json = e.ExtraParams["GridData"].ToString();
StoreSubmitDataEventArgs eSubmit = new StoreSubmitDataEventArgs(json, null);
XmlNode xml = eSubmit.Xml;       

this.Response.Clear();
this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;     
filename=submittedData.xls");
XslCompiledTransform xtExcel = new XslCompiledTransform();       
xtExcel.Load(Server.MapPath("Excel/XSLStyleSheet/Example2.xsl"));
xtExcel.Transform(xml, null, this.Response.OutputStream);
this.Response.End();
```

**Error:**

### Server Error in '/' Application.

OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.

Source Error:

> Line 85:         XslCompiledTransform xtExcel = new XslCompiledTransform();
>   Line 86:         xtExcel.Load(Server.MapPath("Excel/XSLStyleSheet/Example2.xsl"));
>   Line 87:         xtExcel.Transform(xml, null, this.Response.OutputStream);               <============== ERROR LINE
>   Line 88:         this.Response.End();
>   Line 89:     }

Comment: Well the error's got nothing to do with MVC as such. Read the exception description - you can't use `OutputStream` with a custom `TextWriter`.

Comment: @Chris am a beginner in this. tell me how to resolve this or help me how to export the content to excel file in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

@Khalid's suggestion is good. If you really want to write to Excel XML I've had good results doing stuff with the [ClosedXML library](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a simple solution, but why not just ouput your data into a CSV format. Excel has no problems opening CSV spreadsheets.